# On Improper Integral $\int_{a}^{b}{ f\left(x\right) f'\left(x\right) dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a function such that the graph of $f$ is a semicircle $S$ with end points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ where $a<b$.

The improper integral

$$\int_{a}^{b}{ f\left(x\right) f'\left(x\right) dx} $$

is

(A) necessarily zero

(B) possibly zero but not necessarily

(C) necessarily nonexistence

(D) possibly existence but not necessarily

(E) None of the above

This are the following steps I did:
$t = { f\left(x\right) } $

$$I = \int_{f\left(a\right)}^{f\left(b\right)}{t dt} = \frac{f\left(b\right)^{2}  - f\left(a\right)^{2}}{2}  $$

Not clear how (A) could be a correct option answer ?

Comment: Could specify what are a and b?

Comment: How do you know that (A) is the solution? Are you sure it's not a mistake?

Comment: As we don't know the kind of the improperty, only (D) is a valid option. One can easily give examples for $f$ where the integral exists an where not.

Comment: From the link "Questions 28-30 are based on the following information: Let $f$ be a function such that the graph of $f$ is a semicircle $S$ with end points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ where $a<b$". This is a crucial information.

Comment: I have Proven Belwo that A B C And are False

Comment: @PradeepBihani "Let $f$ be a function such that the graph of $f$ is a semicircle $S$ with end points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ where $a<b$" ...

Comment: @kingW3 that is your choice but it says the integral should be improper but what you are doing is completly wrong

Comment: @GuyFsone OP said that the integral is improper changing his solution is wrong (i.e the OP might not know what improper means).

Comment: @PradeepBihani Notice that we do not whether $f(a)$ or  $f(b)$ exist since the integral is improper. I don't think it is a good idea to consider the last line of your computation

Comment: @GuyFsone yah you are right I made that mistake, thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: Unfortunately @kingW3 undo the edit I made on your post.

Comment: $f(x) =  \ln x\implies f'(x)=\frac1x$ and 
$$\color{red}{\int_{0}^{1} f\left(x\right) f'\left(x\right) dx= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x}dx.}$$ and 

$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x}dx =\lim_{a\to 0} \frac12[\ln^2 x]^1_a =\lim_{a\to 0} \frac12 \ln^2 a =+\infty$
 A and D are False
Now consider 
$f(x) = x^{1/4} \implies f'(x) = \frac{x^{-3/4}}{4}$
So  integral,is improper
$$\color{red}{\int_{0}^{1} f\left(x\right) f'\left(x\right) dx= \int_0^1 \frac{x^{-1/2}}{4}dx } = \frac12 $$
This Shows That A is False and C False.
$\int_0^\infty f(x)f'(x) dx = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{2} x^2e^{-2x} = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $f$ be a function such that the graph of $f$ is a semicircle $S$ with end points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ where $a<b$.

This restricts the possibilities for $f$ a lot. It means that either

$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}$$

or

$$f(x) = - \sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)},$$

with the domain being $[a,b]$ in both cases. Thus we know that $f$ is continuously differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, and for $a < \alpha < \beta < b$ we have

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(x)f'(x)\,dx = \frac{f(\beta)^2 - f(\alpha)^2}{2}.$$

Since

$$\lim_{\alpha \downarrow a} f(\alpha) = 0 = \lim_{\beta \uparrow b} f(\beta),$$

it further follows that the improper integral

$$\int_a^b f(x)f'(x)\,dx = \lim_{\substack{\alpha \downarrow a \\ \beta \uparrow b}} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(x)f'(x)\,dx$$

exists, and its value is

$$\frac{f(b)^2-f(a)^2}{2} = \frac{0^2 - 0^2}{2} = 0.$$

Thus (A) is the correct option.

Note that we needed to use some given facts about $f$ to conclude that

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(x) f'(x)\,dx$$

exists for all $a < \alpha \leqslant \beta < b$. If the existence of that integral is implied by any of the hypotheses, then the existence of the improper integral is equivalent to the existence of the two limits $ A = \lim\limits_{\alpha\downarrow a} f(\alpha)$ and $B = \lim\limits_{\beta\uparrow b} f(\beta)$, and the value of the improper integral will be $\frac{1}{2}(B^2 - A^2)$.

Comment: That is ok I just realize additional assumptions were added to the Question.

Comment: There are much more functions besides $f(x) = \sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}$ which graphs are a semi circle.  -1 for that.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe A semicircle with end points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$. That makes it part of the circle with centre $\frac{1}{2}(a+b,0)$ and radius $\frac{1}{2}(b-a)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You’re right, excuse me, please.

Comment: No problem @MichaelHoppe. Mistakes happen.